# Return input to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, input, paragraph

How do I return the input (#input) to my paragraph (#para)?
May seem like a simple answer but not for me since I am a beginner and trying to learn as much as possible. The returned value should come out backwards..

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="head">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="BackTalk.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BackTalk.css">
    <title>BackTalk</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="Main">
        <form>
            <input id="input" type="text">
            <button id="startbutton" onclick="Bata()">Start</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <form id="frm">
        <p id="para"></p>
    </form>
    <div id="bottombtn">
        <button id="resetbtn" onclick="resetbtn">Reset</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startbutton").click(function () {
        var reversed;
        $("#frm").text(reversed);
    });

});

function Bata() {
    var input = $("#input").val();
    var a = input.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = naiveReverse(a[i]);
    }

    var c = a.join(" ");
    var reversed = c;
}

function naiveReverse(aString) {
    var d = aString.split('');
    var e = d.reverse();
    var f = e.join('');
    return f;
}

function resetbtn() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I'm not particularly good at this, so it's not a complete answer, but you're going to have to include a line like the following at the end of your Bata function.  That will set the value of your paragraph "para" to the value of the reversed variable.  What it won't do is get the original string into the function in the first place, and that's not working for me when I try it as a fiddle.  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = reversed;

Comment: @Jason Patterson Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a native jQuery function which takes an array of characters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startbutton").click(function () {
        var reversed = $("#input").val().split("").reverse().join("");
        $("#para").html(reversed);
    });

});
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the input text to wrong id. it should be added to "para" instead of "frm".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startbutton").click(function () {
        var reversed;
        $("#para").text(reversed);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to ask. In your script you are using Jquery. If your want to get any Id using javascript then you can use document.getElementById("para") and if you want to get any object using jquery then it's simple just use $ sign like $("#para") now you can do any operation on these java script object what you want.

If you want to return any value through function then it's also simple

```
function getValue()
{
 var item=document.getELementById("para");
 return item;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my English is not the best :)

Comment: I am only expecting the english which make sense to all stack overflower not expecting best english :)